# Flex AutoComplete with multiple checkbox

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

My requirement is to build a combobox has these functions

1. AutoComplete (like Google's search and prefer not limit to search prefix only)
2. Support multi selection (prefer to use combobox)
3. Can manual input a new value in it

I found [AutoComplete](http://hillelcoren.com/flex-autocomplete/) component can fulfill most my requirement, but it's multi selection is not to show checkbox inside the combobox. If users want to choose 3 items, he needs to search 3 times. It's ok, but not very convenieont. Is there any suggestion for this requirement?

This is the [Demo](http://flex-autocomplete.com/demo/#app=40da&b817-selectedIndex=0) of this component.

[Update] For multi selection, my idea is that if we have the following 6 items in the combobox.

```
AA1
AA2
ABC
AA3
AXX
BAA
```

When user input "AA", then there are only 4 items now. And user can choose more than 1 item without re-search. Use ctrl-click or multi checkbox is ok.

```
AA1
AA2
AA3
BAA
```

Comment: Looks like a very specific requirement, and I doubt you'd find any ready-made solution to this. You'll be better off building your own, or improving upon what you found.

Comment: Did you have a question?  How do you expect the multi-selection to work?  What if something is selected then the user types more characters causing the selected item to be removed from the list?  The Flextras AutoComplete http://www.flextras.com/?event=ProductHome&productID=19 can take care of issue 1; and can easily take care of Issue 3.  Multi-selection is going to require some modifications.

Comment: Given your update; I'll pose you this question:  The user typed "AA" then selects AA2 and AA3.  What happens when the user types 1 after their initial AA?   The two options they selected are no longer in the drop down list.  Should they stay in the drop down list?  Or be removed?  AutoComplete rules say they should be removed; but your ability to select multiples is an uncommon UI requirement. Before this can be coded; you'd have to think this through.

Comment: In my opinion, I think when the user types 1 after their initial AA, all the selected items should be clear. Because these items are not in the filter criteria, keep them is not reasonable and I think it will let program to be more complex.